# Only thumbnails for png files are created correctly in ElFinder

Tags: php, elfinder

I am using ElFinder 2.1.49. When I upload an image thumbnails are only created correctly for png files. Is there some configuration I have to set to accept other file types?

Comment: Thumbnails are being created for the other file types but they are not correct and the image is the same for all other file types.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I really need to get this solved. The demo program supports thumbnails for more file types than just png yet it only seems to work for png files only on my site. Does anyone have any suggestions what I should be looking for?

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion?